# Samsung SM-T395 showing phone layouts for many apps after updating to Android 9

Tags: tablet

A Samsung SM-T395 tablet just upgraded to Android 9.  It seems to now think that the layout is a phone instead of a tablet. It has stopped allowing split screen layouts for some apps.  It is a small tablet, but is there any way to change a setting so it thinks it is a tablet again?

Comment: I'm not sure when this feature was added, but you might want to look for an option along the lines of "Display size" - that would control the effective size of display presented to apps.

Answer (score 1):

We found that Android 9 has a 'Screen Zoom' setting. The upgrade set it to 'Medium', but setting it to 'Small' and the layouts worked fine.